# Using DevExtreme controls in Sharepoint Framework (Microsoft Teams) webpart

Tags: jquery, typescript, microsoft-teams, devextreme, sharepointframework

I'm in the process of building Sharepoint webparts using the Sharepoint Framework. I have followed the steps as described at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part, which results in a solution in TypeScript that opened in Visual Studio Code. In a nutshell, these are the command-line instructions I have executed:

- cd source
- md dev-extreme-test2
- cd dev-extreme-test2
- yo @microsoft/sharepoint
- code .

The next step is to change the render() method to display a simple webpart with a DevExtreme control. This implies making changes to the render() method in the main TypeScript file. For my intents and purposes, I have chosen the Calendar control. Here is my code:

```
import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  PropertyPaneTextField
} from '@microsoft/sp-property-pane';
import { BaseClientSideWebPart } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';

//import styles from './DevExtremeTest2WebPart.module.scss';
//import styles from './content/css/styles'
import * as strings from 'DevExtremeTest2WebPartStrings';

//var styles = require("./content/css/styles.css", "./content/css/dx.dark.css", "./content/css/dx.light.css");
//require('../../../node_modules/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/accordion');

//require('./content/js/UI/calendar');
require('../../../node_modules/devextreme/ui/calendar');

//require("./content/css/styles.css");
// require("./content/css/dx.light.css");
// require("./content/css/dx.dark.css");
require("./content/css/styles.css");
require('../../../node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.light.css');
require('../../../node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.dark.css');

export interface IDevExtremeTest2WebPartProps {
  description: string;
}

export default class DevExtremeTest2WebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart <IDevExtremeTest2WebPartProps> {
  public render(): void {
    this.domElement.innerHTML = 
    `<div class="demo-container">
        <div id="calendar-demo">
            <div class="widget-container">
                <div id="calendar-container"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="options">
                <div class="caption">Options</div>
                <div class="option">
                    <div id="min-date"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="option">
                    <div id="max-date"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="option">
                    <div id="disable-dates"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="option">
                    <div id="first-day"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="option">
                    <div id="custom-cell"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="option">
                    <div id="disabled"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="option">
                    <span>Zoom level</span>
                    <div id="zoom-level"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="option">
                    <span>Selected date</span>
                    <div id="selected-date"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`;
  }

  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
  return Version.parse('1.0');
}

  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
  return {
    pages: [
      {
        header: {
          description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
        },
        groups: [
          {
            groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
            groupFields: [
              PropertyPaneTextField('description', {
                label: strings.DescriptionFieldLabel
              })
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };
}
}
```

But when I try to build and run the solution in Visual Studio Code, I get the following error(s):
In command prompt:

```
[09:16:47] Error - [webpack] 'dist':
./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/icons/dxicons.woff2 1:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected character ' ' (1:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.dark.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.dark.css) 4:41-73
 @ ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.dark.css
 @ ./lib/webparts/devExtremeTest2/DevExtremeTest2WebPart.js
```

On the "dummy" Sharepoint Page:

```
[SPLoaderError.loadComponentError]:
***Failed to load component "bf6c7d07-342b-49b7-bd97-5f193cbdeadb" (DevExtremeTest2WebPart). Original error: ***Failed to load entry point from component "bf6c7d07-342b-49b7-bd97-5f193cbdeadb" (DevExtremeTest2WebPart). Original error: Error loading https://component-id.invalid/bf6c7d07-342b-49b7-bd97-5f193cbdeadb_0.0.1
    Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

***INNERERROR:
***Failed to load entry point from component "bf6c7d07-342b-49b7-bd97-5f193cbdeadb" (DevExtremeTest2WebPart). Original error: Error loading https://component-id.invalid/bf6c7d07-342b-49b7-bd97-5f193cbdeadb_0.0.1
    Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
***CALLSTACK:
Error
    at SPLoaderError.SPError [as constructor] (https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:24453:24)
    at new SPLoaderError (https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:42171:28)
    at Function../sp-loader.js.__WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__.ff4n.ErrorBuilder.buildErrorWithVerboseLog (https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:46165:21)
    at Function../sp-loader.js.__WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__.ff4n.ErrorBuilder.buildLoadComponentError (https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:46034:21)
    at https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:45372:75
```

## What I tried

- I tried building a completely different webpart using a jQuery Accordion control by following the steps here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/reference-third-party-css-styles and trying to follow the same logic with the DevExtreme Calendar control.
- I watched the video here -> https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Visual-Studio-2017-Launch/WEB-104, hoping that I could possibly deploy am HTML-based solution as a webpart, but the video left out way too many steps, so I couldn't actually deploy it to Microsoft Teams.

Please HELP! I've been stuck with this for about a week now!

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Can you please check if sploader is installed or not.